# Understanding Blockchain Reorg

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, proof-of-work

I cannot find any good explanation about these 2 statements about reorg:

1.Reorgs can increase the number of nodes within a blockchain over time, causing a poorer user experience.
Why reorg increases the number of nodes?

2.When reorging becomes more common, attackers only need to beat a portion of honest miners (due to the “longest chain rule”) rather than all of them.
Why is this so?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> 1.Reorgs can increase the number of nodes within a blockchain over time, causing a poorer user experience.

It doesn't. The statement doesn't make sense. Likely the source you are citing is incorrect.

> 2.When reorging becomes more common, attackers only need to beat a portion of honest miners (due to the “longest chain rule”) rather than all of them.

Ethereum doesn't have the longest chain rule, but [the heaviest chain rule](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/uncle-block-cryptocurrency.asp), so this statement needs to be rewritten for Ethereum. Thus, this rule is probably about Bitcoin and other proof-of-work chains that rely on longest chain rule. However, without context, it is not good to have security related discussion.